# Using an AND with OR in an Elastic dev tools query Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm attempting to write a query that contains following logic :

```
if `ts` is greater than or equal to "2021-05-01T04:00:00Z" and less than "2021-10-01T04:00:00Z"
AND
the field data.data1 exists
OR
the field data.data2 exists
OR
the field data.data3 exists
OR
the field data.data4 exists
```

then count the number of records in the index `get_test`

Here is the query I'm utilizing :

```
GET /get_test/_count
{
  "query":{
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"range": {"ts": {"gte": "2021-05-01T04:00:00Z", "lt": "2021-10-01T04:00:00Z"}}},
        {"exists": {"field": "data.data1"}},
        {"exists": {"field": "data.data2"}},
        {"exists": {"field": "data.data4"}},
        {"exists": {"field": "data.data3"}}
      ]
      
    }
  }
}
```

This query executes in Elastic dev tools but 0 results are returned but records that match the above logic exist. It seems there is an implicit AND between each invocation of :

```
    {"exists": {"field": "data.data1"}},
    {"exists": {"field": "data.data2"}},
    {"exists": {"field": "data.data4"}},
    {"exists": {"field": "data.data3"}}
```

What change do I need to make to the elastic query to enable above logic ? Is there a way to define an `OR` between each of the exists clauses ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the field `data` of type `nested`, you must have all those criteria under a `nested` query:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "ts": {
                            "gte": "2021-05-01T04:00:00Z",
                            "lt": "2021-10-01T04:00:00Z"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "data",
                        "query": {
                            "should": [
                                {
                                    "exists": {
                                        "field": "data.data1"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "exists": {
                                        "field": "data.data2"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "exists": {
                                        "field": "data.data4"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "exists": {
                                        "field": "data.data3"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Note that under the `nested` query, I use `should` instead of `must`, because you only need one of those fields to be existed (`OR`)